# ng-bootstrap modal fails in unit test

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I am facing a problem where a NgbModal is not opened in a test harness. The problem occurs when I try to open a modal inside a modal service:

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ModalService {
  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {}

  /**
   * Opens an extra large modal dialog
   * @param component The content component
   */
  openExtraLarge<T>(component: Type<T>): NgbModalRef {
    return this.modalService.open(component, { windowClass: 'dark-modal', size: 'xl', centered: true });
  }
}
```

My test harness:

```js
describe('ModalService', () => {
  let service: ModalService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({});
    service = TestBed.inject(ModalService);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should open a dialog directly in the test', () => {
    spyOn(service, 'openExtraLarge');

    const myModal = service.openExtraLarge(TestModalComponent);

    expect(service.openExtraLarge).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(myModal).not.toBeUndefined();
  });

});
```

I have created a stackblitz example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-modal-unit-test?file=src%2Fapp%2Fservices%2Fmodal.service.spec.ts)

I suspect the problem is related to the fact that the Component is not injected in the service, but the test fails silently (Expected undefined not to be undefined).

What could be the source of my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you intercepted the original call and expect that it will still return some value.

```
spyOn(service, 'openExtraLarge');
```

This means that you completely changed behavior of `openExtraLarge` method. And it returns nothing(`undefined`)

If you want that it returns something you should tell spy what to return, e.g.:

```
spyOn(service, 'openExtraLarge').and.returnValue('something');
```

or you can event execute original method but should properly configure your testing module:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [TestModalComponent],
  entryComponents: [TestModalComponent]
})
export class TestModule {}

...
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [TestModule, NgbModalModule]
});

...

spyOn(service, 'openExtraLarge').and.callThrough();
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-modal-unit-test-wc59jw?file=src/app/services/modal.service.spec.ts)**

Comment: That was indeed the problem! I was expecting that `.and.callThrough()` actually was the 'default' behaviour when no other option was supplied, which seems to be false. Thank you very much for your help and your forked stackblitz example.